# What does the first $1$ mean in $\ce{Li}_2 1 ^1\Sigma_g^+: (1s\sigma_g)^2(1s \sigma_u)^2(2s \sigma_g)^2$?

Tags: nomenclature, molecules

I am trying to learn the nomenclature behind molecular states and in (Demtröder, 2010) I came across this expression:
 $$\ce{Li}_2 \color{red}{1} ^1\Sigma_g^+: (1s\sigma_g)^2(1s \sigma_u)^2(2s \sigma_g)^2$$
now I can explain the origin of every term except the $1$ which I have put in red. What does this 1 mean?

Comment: It probably denotes the state of the inner electrons.

Comment: @aventurin are you sure, this would seem like a very redundant piece of information  since I can already see what state the inner electrons are in - and in any case surly in most cases this will be $1$.

Comment: No, I'm not sure.

Comment: I could not find your example in Demtroder's Laser Spectroscopy book, but found on p575-576 $\ce{Na}3~ ^2P_{3/2}$ in which the $3$ refers to the Rydberg series starting at the 3P level so $n=3$ . He also uses notation such as $3\mathrm {p}^{3\mathrm P}$ to indicate a 3P state arising from a 3p level.

Comment: @porphyrin I think you are right, this [pdf](http://scienide2.uwaterloo.ca/~rleroy/c740/Toolkit.pdf) describes the classification on pg15-16 and that it has replaced the conventional, $X$, $A$, $B$... and $a$, $b$,... notations. If you want to write up an answer summarizing this I will accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The conventional labelling of molecular states starts at X for the lowest state and A, B, C for higher ones and a, b, c, for equivalent states of the same symmetry but different multiplicity; see Herzberg spectroscopy books for many examples. These labels, however, reflect the order in which the states were discovered and so do not reflect their relative energies. It is becoming more common to precede a molecular state's symmetry label by an integer e.g. $1~^1\Sigma _g^+,~ 2~^1\Sigma _g^+,~3~^1\Sigma _g^+$ to reflect the energy ordering of states with the same symmetry. This notation reflects the way atomic levels of the same symmetry are labelled as $1$s, $2$s, $3$s, etc.

As an example, the conventional notation for the first four electronic states of  $\ce{C2}$ in order of energy is

X $^3\Pi_u$ ;  a $^1\Sigma_g^+$ ; b $^1\Pi_u$ ; A $^3\Pi_g$

which becomes

$1~ ^3\Pi_u$ ;  $2 ~^1\Sigma_g^+$ ; $1 ^1\Pi_u$ ; $3~ ^3\Pi_g$

In atoms the notation for a set of transitions starting from the 3p level in sodium is  Na $3~ ^2P_{3/2}$ .